# How to use polymer.js to toggle hidden/show of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I have two types of paper-card elements in the html page

```
<paper-card done> 
<paper-card>
```

There is also a button

```
<paper-icon-button icon="menu" on-tap="_show"></paper-icon-button>
```

I would like to use the `_show` function to set the style of `<paper-card done>` to toggle its view state, i.e., toggle `display` between `none` and `block`. How to use polymer to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the fastest way to hide/show something in polymer is to use the "hidden" attribute with a boolean property and binding. Here is an example.

```
<paper-card done hidden$="[[hideDone]]">
```

The '$' before the equal is for telling polymer it's a boolean property and to handle it accordingly.

Then all you have to do is a

```
this.set('hideDone', true)
```

in your '_show' function, and that should do the trick :)

To show it again, just set the property to false again, and so on.

Comment: Can you also use this.hideDone=true;?

Comment: it does work in my case as well. But the thing is, 'this.set('hideDone', true)' doesn't seem to really update a variable, because just after that I do 'console.log(hideDone)' then it says hideDone is not defined. Anyone knows about this?

Comment: when using this.set() the var is updated in the 'this' var of the component so it is 'console.log(this.hideDone)' you have to do